# numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I'm new to both Linux and Python. I'm working on a Ubuntu 16.04.

My original Python is

`python --version
 Python 2.7.8`

I'm trying to import numpy into python3. However, when I try to import numpy I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line
> >     16, in  from . import multiarray 
> >     ImportError:
> >     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so:
> >     undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> > Traceback (most recent call
> >     last): File "", line 1, in  File
> >     "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/**init**.py", line 142,
> >     in  from . import add_newdocs File
> >     "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line
> >     13, in  from numpy.lib import add_newdoc File
> >     "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/**init**.py", line
> >     8, in  from .type_check import * File
> >     "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line
> >     11, in  import numpy.core.numeric as _nx File
> >     "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line
> >     26, in  raise ImportError(msg)
>
> ImportError: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.
>
> > Most likely you are trying
> >     to import a failed build of numpy. 
> >     If you're working with a numpy git
> >     repo, try git clean -xdf (removes all files not under version
> >     control). Otherwise reinstall numpy.
>
> Original error was:
>
> > /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so:
> >     undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct"

The python I'm using to import numpy is Python 3.5.2 and it seems to be trying to use the package in Python 2.7.

### I've tried :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

### and also :

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall 
sudo apt install python3-numpy python3-scipy
```

It seems a similar problem to what others have faced but none of the solutions seem to work?

Answer (score 1):

You installed pip for both python2.7 and python3. To use pip of python3 just you need to use pip3 instead of pip.

```
pip3 install package
```

Comment: Thanks @pbuzulan but then I get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'`

Comment: try to upgrade pip3 and then try again:
pip3 install --upgrade pip

Comment: same error message `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'`

Comment: try to:
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall

Comment: or try to install the libraries with python3 -m pip package

Comment: That says it's sucessful but with the following error message `The directory '/<mylabname>/home/emily/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
The directory '/<mylabname>/home/emily/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. ...cont.`

Comment: put sudo before.  
sudo python3 -m pip package

Comment: whilst  `python3 -m pip numpy
ERROR: unknown command "numpy"`

Comment: sudo python3 -m pip numpy returns the same ERROR: unknown command "numpy"

Comment: you miss the keyword install after pip

Comment: Sorry. Doing sudo python3 -m pip install numpy returns the same long error as above but also `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Comment: the package should be installed at this point. now you have to upgrade your pip:
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip or python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: by the way, to check if a library is installed: pip3 list | grep -F numpy

Comment: Thanks for all your help. That's Successfully installed pip-19.0.3 but still with the same long warning error above. Do I need to just do now sudo pip3 install numpy?

Comment: hmmm doing the checking for a library gives me `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
` again

Comment: Doing sudo pip3 install numpy gives me the same long error message above. and also `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.16.2)` when I enter python3 and import numpy as np I get the original `Original error was: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct` I started with?